# Facebook API: Invalid page token when trying to subscribe to the application

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to subscribe my Facebook page to my application. I'm following the [official docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/guides/lead-ads/webhooks/v2.5). I called `/me/accounts` edge and got list of my pages with access tokens, as expected. Then, I called `/1234567890123456/subscribed_apps` edge (where 1234567890123456 is my page's ID) and passed the `access_token` that I got before, as explained in the docs. The docs doesn't say if it's GET or POST request, I assume it's POST though, because it's inserting. [This help page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/subscribed_apps) confirms it should be a POST. I tried both though. In both cases, I'm getting the following error:

> (#210) A page access token is required to request this resource.

I'm using Graph API Explorer with `v2.5`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How exactly did you pass the access token in GAE? Via the access token input field on top, or as an additional POST parameter?

Comment: I had it as the field, I think it's what I did wrong. The request worked correctly through PHP SDK.

Comment: In the Graph API Explorer, there's a dropdown with "Get Token". There, you can select the Page; the GX will then use that Page Access Token. You don't need to manually pass it around, when working with the GX.

Comment: @Roemer Yes, you are right. Even more - you CAN'T do it manually, because it seems like Graph API Explorer overwrites the `access_token` field with the actual access token used for request. In other words, that field sets `access_token` property with higher priority.